# Wordpress. Вывод в меню рубрик и заголовков записей

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите как можно реализовать меню с записями, чтобы была видна иерархия рубрик, но при этом сразу указывались ссылки на записи? wp_list_categories выводит почти то, что нужно, то есть рубрики в меню есть, но сами записи он не выводит. Возможно есть другая функция для подобного? Заранее благодарен!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Список записей в меню?? Да ещё постоянно меняющийся? Жуть какая.. Или такое хочешь изобрести  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sitemap-page/ ?

Comment: Да, что то в таком плане, только чисто записи и разделы

Comment: Ну так возьми готовый плагин. Таких море.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для двухуровневой структуры (рубрика -> подрубрики) задачу можно решить следующим образом (для многоуровневой логика будет та же, просто больше проверок на вложенность):

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(); /*получаем все рубрики*/ ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
    <?php if($category->parent == 0): /*проверяем, является ли рубрика родительской*/ ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id) ?>"><?php echo $category->name; /* выводим ссылку и название */ ?></a>
            <?php $posts = get_posts('category='.$category->term_id); if($posts): /*проверяем, есть ли посты у родительской рубрики, и если есть, выводим*/ ?>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
                    <li><em><small><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></small></em></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $sub_categories = get_categories(['parent'  => $category->term_id]); if($sub_categories): /*проверяем, есть ли у рубрики подрубрики, и если есть, выводим*/ ?>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach($sub_categories as $sub_category): ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($sub_category->term_id) ?>"><?php echo $sub_category->name; ?></a>
                        <?php $sub_posts = get_posts('category='.$sub_category->term_id); if($sub_posts): /*аналогичная история с постами подрубрик*/ ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ($sub_posts as $post): ?>
                                <li><em><small><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></small></em></li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<ul>
```

Тут важно понимать, что если одна и та же запись находится в нескольких рубриках/подрубриках, то ссылка на неё будет продублирована в каждой из них (т.е. по идее запись должна иметь только одну рубрику или подрубрику).

И если у родительских рубрик есть свои записи, то в меню ссылки на них будут выводиться на одном уровне со ссылками на подрубрики. Понятно, что стилями можно отделить одно от другого (я даже в разметке добавил теги `<em><small>`), но с т.з. восприятия всё равно это будет выглядеть в меню довольно странно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, почти то, что нужно, только можно уточнить как избавить от дубля?  Добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Cowboy, вот я как раз на этом моменте и заострил внимание в своём ответе: _если одна и та же запись находится в нескольких рубриках/подрубриках, то ссылка на неё будет продублирована в каждой из них_. Единственное оптимальное решение - прикреплять запись только к одной рубрике или подрубрике.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!